# check string or int

Tags: java, input

I'm reading a string with following format:
ID First Name(contain Middle Name) Last Name birthYear

For example

722 David Beckham 1975

Right now I'm simply using this code:

```
ID = scannerStr.nextInt();

FirstName = scannerStr.next();

LastName = scannerStr.next();

BirthYr = scannerStr.nextInt();
```

But you see when people with middle name show up, this fails...
For example

100 David Robert Joseph Beckham 1958

How to fix this anyone? How do I check if what I read is a word or int?

Comment: How do I check if what I read is a word or int? @BrianRoach

Comment: Your "format" has commas in it, and your data doesn't. This... seems like a problem.

Comment: You can use `Scanner#hasNextXYZ()`

Comment: oops, sorry, commas gone now.

Comment: Here's a C# Regex way of doing it.            string input = "722 Fred Jones 1975";
            var matches = Regex.Match(input, @"^(?<id>\d+)\s(?<fname>\w+)\s(?<mname>\w+\s)?(?<lname>\w+)\s(?<byear>\d{2,4})$");

            string id = matches.Groups["id"].Value;
            string fname = matches.Groups["fname"].Value;
            string mname = matches.Groups["mname"].Value;
            string lname = matches.Groups["lname"].Value;
            string byear = matches.Groups["byear"].Value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have modeled your input incorrectly.

Your current model (as represented in your code) is this:

```
int string string int
```

The real model for your input appears to be this:

```
int string (string)* string int
```

You can correctly parse this using `String.split()`

```
String[] tokens = inputString.split(" ");

actorId = Integer.valueOf(tokens[0]);
actorFirstName = tokens[1];
actorLastName = tokens[tokens.length - 2];
actorBirthYear = Integer.valueOf(tokens[tokens.length - 1]);
```

Check out the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) StringUtils class for null safe string manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the best solution is to split everything and save each word on a string array, the last word will be a number, the first one will be an id and you can know that the word before the last one is the surname, the rest is just name! code is not tested, this code can split the first word on a text, apply it to the whole string and you're done!

```
boolean flag = true;
String someWord ="";
int j = 0;
int i = 0;
String[] wordCollector;
while (flag) {
 if (word.substring(i,i+1).equals(" ")) {
  someWord = someWord + word.substring(i,i+1);
  i++;
 }
 else {
 wordCollector[j] = 
 j++;
 flag = false;
 someWord="";
 }
}
```